# How to get name of actor reference in akka?

Tags: scala, akka

Actor[akka://application/user/**harish@govind**#1668753534]

This is the reference of the chat room i want to **get the name (harish@govind)** of the room but i have no idea about it.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
<Your ActorRef here>.path.name
```